# WPF Data Bind from a instantiated class in project A to Project B

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am having a issue with data binding from a instantiated class in project A to Project B. The data binding "seems" to be working correctly; however, I am definitely getting a different instantiation of ClassA.

This is the ClassA - which is a class in a different Project. ClassA is a console application and has a main.

```
public class ClassA: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _partNumber;
   private Guid _guid = Guid.NewGuid ( );

   // Make a singleton of this class so other classes have to request an instance
   private static readonly ClassA _Instance = new ClassA ( );

   //
   //.. Read in xml file "This executes properly - I've checked"
   //

   public static ClassA GetInstance ( )
   {
       return _Instance;
   }

   public string PartNumber
    {
        get
        {

            if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty ( _partNumber ) )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got PartNumber: " + _partNumber + "  GUID: " + _guid);
                return "Empty";
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Got PartNumber: " + _partNumber + "  GUID: " + _guid);
            return _partNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( value == null )
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException ( "value" );
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Set Partnumber: " + value + "  GUID: " + _guid);
            _partNumber = value;
        }
    }

}
```

This is ClassB - which is a class in a different Project. ClassB is a WPF application.

```
class ClassB : Binding
{
    public ClassB ( )
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public ClassB ( string path ) : base ( path )
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize ( )
    {
        Source = ClassA.GetInstance();
    }
}
```

This is the XAML code that calls the binding

```
<controls:MetroWindow ... ...

   xmlns:db ="clr-namespace:EAS.GUI"

   <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
     Style="{StaticResource LblTextData}"   
     Text="{db:ClassB PartNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, OneWay}" 

   ... ...

</controls:MetroWindow>
```

When I run the program I run `Console.WriteLine()` to verify the data and GUID's. The data printed from ClassB is null and the GUID's are totally different from ClassA. My question is how can I get the same class instance - rather then a totally different instance?

Here is the Console output:

```
Set Partnumber: 736543  GUID: 360a6dcc-a719-4ad0-a929-6f3ed09eefb2
Get PartNumber:         GUID: 2405b370-0806-4f41-91c6-0fdd6f894077
```

---

**Okay** so I changed my approach and got rid of `ClassB` and removed `xmlns:db ="clr-namespace:EAS.GUI"` from the XAML namespace definitions.

In my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I added this line in the constructor:
    DataContext = ClassA.GetInstance();

Then in my `MainWindow.xaml` I changed the textblock to this:

```
<TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
 Style="{StaticResource LblTextData}"
 Text="{Binding PartNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Now I am getting this in the Output window at runtime:

*System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=PartNumber; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')*

Comment: Did you mean `Text="{db:ClassB ..."`? I don't see any `ClassB` references in your XAML.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for the quick reply. ClassB is being referenced though the namespace `xmlns:db ="clr-namespace:EAS.GUI"`

Comment: Right, but your text says "ClassA" not "ClassB"

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks. Unfortunately that was a typo when copying the solution in stackoverflow. I fixed the typo.

Comment: I tried to simulate your, it is working fine. may be if you post more code it will help to solve the problem.

Comment: @Ganesh Is each class is in two different projects in a solution and a xml (or data file) is read in at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know for certain what the correct answer to this question would be without a more complete code example. Preferably [an *actual* complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In terms of debugging: you should mark the `_guid` field as `readonly`, and for completeness, add `private ClassA() { }` to the `ClassA` class, i.e. make its constructor private, to prevent code from obtaining an instance through any means other than the `GetInstance()` method.

As you might guess from the above, I suspect that you in fact have some code somewhere (which you failed to include in your post) that creates an extra instance of `ClassA`. Note that in WPF, object instantiation in XAML relies on public, parameterless constructors for types. You may have declared some object of type `ClassA` in your XAML somewhere, causing WPF to create the extra instance on your behalf. In any case, wherever the code is that does that is, by making the constructor private, you will prevent it from happening, most likely causing an error to be generated at compile time that leads you directly to the problem.

If not, then you should edit your question so that it includes a good, complete code example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll give that a try at work tomorrow. Unfortunately I cannot post much more since a lot of the code is proprietary. If your solution doesn't work, I'll work on posting more code tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: I did what you suggested and still no success; however, I did change things around a little and now I'm actually getting an error. I posted my changes above.